# getDerivedStateFromProps, change of state under the influence of changing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I click Item -> I get data from url:`https: // app / api / v1 / asset / $ {id}`. The data is saved in `loadItemId`. I am moving `loadItemId` from the component `Items` to the component `Details`, then to the component `AnotherItem`.
Each time I click `Item` the props `loadItemId` changes in the `getDerivedStateFromProps` method. Problem: I'll click `Element D` -> I see in console.log 'true', then I'll click `Element E` --> It display in console.log `true` and`false` simultaneously, and it should display only `false`.

Trying to create a ternary operator `{this.state.itemX ['completed'] ? this.start () : ''}`. If `{this.state.itemX ['completed']` call the function `this.start ()`

Code here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y43r9d)

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwGY5.jpg

**Items**

```
class Items extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {   
      itemId: null,  
      loadItemId: ''
    }
  }

  selectItem = (id) => {
    this.setState({
      itemId: id
    })

        this.load(id);
  }

    load = (id) => {

        axios.get
            axios({
                    url: `https://app/api/v1/asset/${id}`,
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`           
                    }
            })
            .then(response => {
                    this.setState({
                            loadItemId: response.data
                    });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
            })
}

  render () {
    return (
            <div > 
                <Item
                    key={item.id}
                    item={item}
                    selectItem={this.selectItem}
                >
                <Details
                    loadItemId={this.state.loadTime}  
                /> 
            </div>
    )
  }
```

---

**Item**

```
class Item extends Component {
  render () {

    return (
      <div  onClick={() => this.props.selectItem(item.id}>

      </div>
    )
  } 
}
```

---

**Details**

```
class Details extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

  render () {
    return (
            <div> 
                <AnotherItem 
                    loadItemId = {this.props.loadItemId}        
                />       
            </div>
    )
  } 
}
```

---

**AnotherItem**

```
class AnotherItem extends Component {


  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      itemX: ''
    };
  }


  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if(nextProps.loadItemId !== prevState.loadItemId) {
      return { itemX: nextProps.loadItemId }
    }

  render () {
      console.log(this.state.itemX ? this.state.itemX['completed'] : '');

    {/*if this.state.loadX['completed'] === true, call function this.start()*/ }
    return (
            <button /*{this.state.loadX['completed'] ? this.start() : ''}*/ onClick={this.start}>
                Start
            </button>      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is minor, but you should consider naming the function that loads the item and the item itself differently. It's easier to follow what the code is doing when only one thing is named `loadItem` (especially if that's the only thing that loads the item).

Comment: why do you need state in AnotherItem at all? Just use the prop value

Comment: @thedude Did you see my example: `https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y43r9d` ?                      I click element -> fetch Id -> id paste into url -> fetch status value true or false -> move to AnotherItem -> if true I run the button  (calls the function pinned to the button)

Comment: @Umbro I did look at the code, and it does not call the function as you said. That code is commented out. It would be helpful if you explained in some detail what you are trying to accomplish here

Answer (score 1):

here:

```
selectItem = (id) => {
    this.setState({
        itemId: id
    })

    this.load(id);
}
```

you call setState(), then 'Item' and 'Details' and 'AnotherItem' call their render method. so you see log for previous 'loadItemId'.

when 'load' method work done. here:

```
 this.setState({
     loadItemId: response.data
 });
```

you setState() again, then 'Item' and 'Details' and 'AnotherItem' call their render method again. in this time you see log for new 'loadItemId'.

---

## solution

setState both state in one place. after load method done, instead of:

```
 this.setState({
     loadItemId: response.data
 });
```

write:

```
 this.setState({
     itemId: id,
     loadItemId: response.data
 });
```

---

and remove:

```
this.setState({
  itemId: id
})
```

from 'selectItem' method.

Answer (score 0):

Need some clarification, but think I can still address this at high level. As suggested in comment above, with the information presented, it does not seem that your component AnotherItem actually needs to maintain state to determine the correct time at which to invoke start() method (although it may need to be stateful for other reasons, as noted below).

It appears the functionality you are trying to achieve (invoke start method at particular time) can be completed solely with a comparison of old/new props by the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method. As provided by the React docs, getDerivedStateFromProps is actually reserved for a few 'rare' cases, none of which I believe are present here. Rather, it seems that you want to call a certain method, perhaps perform some calculation, when new props are received and meet a certain condition (e.g., not equal to old props). That can be achieved by hooking into componentDidUpdate.

```
class AnotherItem extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state  = {}
   }

   start = () => { do something, perform a calculation }

  // Invoked when new props are passed
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

     // Test condition to determine whether to call start() method based on new props,
     // (can add other conditionals limit number of calls to start, e.g., 
     // compare other properties of loadItemId from prevProps and this.props) .
     if (this.props.loadItemId && this.props.loadItemId.completed === true) {

         //Possibly store result from start() in state if needed
         const result = this.start();
      } 

    }
  }

    render () {
       // Render UI, maybe based on updated state/result of start method if 
       // needed
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 'loadItemId' it is object. It has property 'completed' If loadItemId['completed'] is true I want to call function 'start'

Comment: Understood - the generally approach I set forth still stands, I believe, but will update response to reflect that

Comment: @Umbro... please let me know if you would like additional clarification

Comment: And what if the object has no completed value? `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'completed' of null`. `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

Comment: As noted in the comments, you can perform any number of conditional checks in componentDidUpdate. To your point, I've added a check to see if loadItemId is falsy (encompassing a value of null). These conditional checks are important, particularly if you are mutating state from componentDidUpdate, as you may generate an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering this behaviour because you are changing `state` of `Items` component on each click with

```
this.setState({
    itemId: id
})
```

When changing its `state`, `Items` component rerenders causing `AnotherItem` to rerender (because that is child component) with it's previous `state` which has `completed` as `true` (since you've clicked element D before). Then async request completes and another rerender is caused with

```
this.setState({
    loadItemId: response.data
});
```

which initiates another `AnotherItem` rerender and expected result which is `false`.

Try removing `state` change in `selectItem` and you'll get desired result.

I'd suggest you read [this article](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) and try to structure your code differently.

**EDIT**
You can easily fix this with adding loader to your component:

```
selectItem = (id) => {
    this.setState({
        itemId: id,
        loading: true
    })

    this.load(id);
}

load = (id) => {
    axios.get
        axios({
            url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`,
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                loadItemId: response.data
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}


render() {
    return (
        <div >
            <ul>
                {this.state.items.map((item, index) =>
                    <Item
                        key={item.id}
                        item={item}
                        selectItem={this.selectItem}
                    />
                )
                }
            </ul>
            {this.state.loading ? <span>Loading...</span> : <Details
                itemId={this.state.itemId}
                loadItemId={this.state.loadItemId}
            />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This way, you'll rerender your `Details` component only when you have data fetched and no unnecessary rerenders will occur.

Comment: I have to delete all: this.setState({
      itemId: id
    })
?

Comment: Yes, if you delete that line, no rerender will occur until axios async request finishes (because there is no setState called before request finishes). Because when you click D, after async action AnotherItem updates it state accordingly, but after clicking on another element, immediate rerender is caused and AnotherItem rerenders with same state that was set when you clicked on D. After async action new correct state will be applied.

Comment: I can't delete this.setState({
      itemId: id
    }); Maybe put `this.load(id);` in another place?